# How do I use an array from an external JS file in a Vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to import an array into a Vue component:

**The (simplified) component:**

```
<script type="text/babel">
    const countryCodes = require('./country_codes.js');

    export default {
        props: [],

        data() {
            return {
                countryCodes: countryCodes
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**country_codes.js**

```
(function() {
   return ['DE', 'EN']; // This, of course, is way bigger; simplified for readability
});
```

Both the component and the country_codes.js files are in the same directory, but the `countryCodes` property is always an empty object.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't tell for what reason your code isn't working. Maybe you just need to export your data from countryCodes.js

So, I am sure this will work

```
import countryCodes from './countryCodes.js'
```

countryCodes.js

```
export const countryCodes = {
  return ['DE', 'EN'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That put me on the right track. Plus cour code works just fine.

Comment: Strange. For me it shoots an error:  `Unexpected keyword 'return' (2:4)` Any hints on that?

Comment: Maybe you don't have es6 support